# SAS MERGE returns only one row

Tags: sas

In SAS, I have run a simple linear regression and outputted my results to `work.outdata` (columns include residual, prediction, standard error) using the following code:

```
proc reg data=model_file;
model &y = &x;
output out=work.outdata r=resid;
title 'model';
run; quit;
```

I am trying to join this output data back to the original dataset, called `work.modeldata`. The ID I want to join by is `u_id`. I use the following code to do so in the same macro:

```
data work.mergedf;
    merge work.modeldata work.outdata;
    by u_id;
run;
```

However, my newly merged data set only contains one row (I have thousands of rows), with `u_id = 1`- that row is indeed merged correctly though. I've scoured through the SAS documentation [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001107839.htm), and believe I have sorted the datasets properly- all the IDs are sorted ascending and appear to match in each dataset. However, the log file returns the same error:

`ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.MODELDATA.`

I'm really at a loss for what is causing this issue. I've attempted using `PROC SORT`, but the log file Does anyone have any insights into why only one row is being returned?

EDIT: Thanks to Joe's suggestions (look at accepted answer), I was able to get this working. Here's the final code I used that produced the correct merging:

```
proc sort data=work.model_file; by u_id; run;
proc sort data=work.outdata; by u_id; run; 

data work.merged_data;
    merge work.model_file work.outdata;
    by u_id;
run;
```

Comment: Where does MODELDATA come from?  Your PROC REG only has reference to MODEL_FILE and OUTDATA.

Comment: @data_null_ it's the same. I just renamed it and forgot to change the variable name when posting to SO.

Comment: What variable is `U_ID` and why would you think that any of the three datasets mentioned in your code would be sorted by that variable?

Comment: @Tom `U_ID` is the primary key for the tables, and I believe it is sorted by that variable because all of the tables currently list the rows with `U_ID` ascending. I checked the first 50 rows of each table and they all match `U_ID`s.

Comment: Try sorting again with `proc sort` and see if they really are sorted. If your variables are character and have values like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 then they are NOT sorted since 10 should be between 1 and 2.

Comment: Is the `modeldata` table orinigally stored as a SAS dataset or does it come from some other DBMS? In other words, is `work.modeldata` the result of a sorting operation performed on table from a third party database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to answer this without seeing your actual data, but what can be posted is steps for "what to do when I think my dataset is sorted but SAS disagrees".

1. Run PROC SORT on both datasets.  Even if you think they're sorted. If they're sorted and SAS already knows they are, it won't even sort them, but otherwise this will resort them the way SAS wants them.
2. If you're using data from an alternate DBMS than SAS (so from SQL Server, Oracle, Hadoop, etc.), don't run `PROC SORT` directly on that DBMS's data: bring it into SAS as a SAS dataset, then `PROC SORT` that dataset.  Sometimes other DBMSs make different choices as to how to handle certain cases that you don't necessarily want.
3. Make sure both datasets have identical variable lengths.  It can easily be a problem that they don't.
4. Make sure you actually have the BY variable correct, and that it has something in it.  The number of times I've had blank BY variables, or with things other than I expected, is far too high to leave this seemingly obvious detail out.

Comment: These are all excellent suggestions. The data cannot be published at all, unfortunately so I know it's a bit limiting in terms of debugging. I ultimately did get it to work, and it did involving sorting BOTH datasets properly. I made an edit to my question to reflect what helped!